# Decomposition of even symmetric polynomials and Euler numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-polynomials

Let's denote the even part of a polynomial $p$ by $E[p]$, which means only taking into account the monomials in $p$ which are even in all the arguments. Now let's consider the even part of the symmetric polynomial $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{2k}$. For example, $E[(x_1+x_2+x_3)^{4}] = x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+6x_1^2x_2^2+6x_2^2x_3^2+6x_3^2x_1^2$. It's clear that $E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{2k}]$ is a symmetric polynomial in terms of $x_1^2, x_2^2, \cdots, x_n^2$, which can be decomposed into [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_0(x_1^2, x_2^2, \cdots, x_n^2)$, $e_1(x_1^2, x_2^2, \cdots, x_n^2)$, $\cdots$, $e_n(x_1^2, x_2^2, \cdots, x_n^2)$, by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. For example, 
\begin{align}
E[(x_1+x_2+x_3)^{4}] =& x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+6x_1^2x_2^2+6x_2^2x_3^2+6x_3^2x_1^2\\
=& (x_1^2+ x_2^2+ x_3^2)^2 + 4 (x_1^2x_2^2+x_2^2x_3^2+x_3^2x_1^2)=e_1^2+4e_2.
\end{align}
I further worked out the first few cases:
\begin{align}
E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{2}] =& e_1\\
E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{4}] =& e_1^2+4e_2\\
E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{6}] =& e_1^3 + 12 e_1e_2 + 48 e_3\\
E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{8}] =& e_1^4 + 24 e_1^2 e_2 + 16 e_2^2 + 256 e_1 e_3 + 1088 e_4\\
E[(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^{10}] =& e_1^5 + 40 e_1^3 e_2 + 80 e_1 e_2^2 + 800 e_1^2 e_3 + 
 640 e_2 e_3 + 9280 e_1 e_4 + 39680 e_5
\end{align}
Now my question is what is the general formula for this decomposition, like the [Newton's Identites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which can be written in terms of generating functions or determinants?

Some observations I have made include: The coefficients of terms $e_1^{k-2i}e_2^{i}$ are $2^{2i}\binom{k}{2i}$. The coefficients of $e_k$ are [A024255](https://oeis.org/A024255), which are related to the alternating permutations, Euler numbers and Genocchi numbers.